# R S4 object datatype hash

Tags: r, r-s4

Is there a datatype for hash? I tried to genereate a class with datatype character for hash values but I got error:

> Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class "Picture" object: 1:
> invalid object for slot "mD5sum" in class "Picture": got class "hash",
> should be or extend class "character" invalid class "Picture" object
> 2: invalid object for slot "sHA1sum" in class "Picture": got class
> "hash", should be or extend class "character" Calls: <.....

Generate class code:

```
setClass("Picture", slots=list(id="numeric", mD5sum="character", sHA1sum="character"))
```

Adding data to class (this gives error):

```
md5sum <- as.character(openssl::md5(file(full_file_path)))
sha1sum <- as.character(openssl::sha1(file(full_file_path)))
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=1, mD5sum=md5sum, sHA1sum=sha1sum)
```

Full code chunk:

````
```{r}
setClass("Picture", slots=list(id="numeric", mD5sum="character", sHA1sum="character"))
full_file_path <- "testphoto.JPG"
md5sum <- as.character(openssl::md5(file(full_file_path)))
sha1sum <- as.character(openssl::sha1(file(full_file_path)))
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=1, mD5sum=md5sum, sHA1sum=sha1sum)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

No, `hash` is not an *atomic type* (the closest idea R has to a "data type"). Hash values (such as from `openssl::md5`) are generally output as `character` (though in principle they could be `integer` if the output was small enough).

If you want to know whether a class exists or not, you can use `isClass`:

```
> isClass("hash")
[1] FALSE
> isClass("character")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: How come I got the error "Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class "Picture" object: 1: invalid object for slot "mD5sum" in class "Picture": got class "hash", should be or extend class "character" ?

Comment: Did you do something like `class(x) <- "hash"`? That uses the S3 mechanism not S4 and probably won't work as you want it to.

Comment: Yes, I tired that. I am using S4.